# Image Load Problems from URL in Android

Tags: android, image, web-services

I am trying to load images from url, in Android 2.2 Images are load but not in Android 4.0 ICS. What is the problem behind it? and is there any another way to do like this.

My Code is

```
public class Photos extends Activity {

public static final String TAG_IMAGE_NAME = "image_name";
public static final String TAG_IMAGE_THUMB_NAME = "image_thumb_name";
public static String URL = "http://......./...../....../mainAPI.php";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> photoList;
String responseData = null;
static GridView gridView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photos);
    gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    photoList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    new AsyncData().execute();


}

class AsyncData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Photos.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Loading....");
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rquest","{\"method\":\"photogallery\",\"body\":[{}]}"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            responseData = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            try {
                JSONArray data = new JSONArray(responseData);
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                    String photoName = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE_NAME);
                    String imageThumbName = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE_THUMB_NAME);
                    map.put(TAG_IMAGE_NAME, photoName);
                    map.put(TAG_IMAGE_THUMB_NAME, imageThumbName);
                    photoList.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(Photos.this, R.layout.photo_row, photoList);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

ImageAdapter Class.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>{
Context context;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList;
HashMap<String, String> myData;
int layout;
public ImageAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<HashMap<String, String>> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    this.myList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) objects;
    this.layout = textViewResourceId;
}

@Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View row = null;
    ImageView image = null;
    Bitmap bimage;
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
    myData = myList.get(position);
    try{
        image = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imagePhoto);
        String uri = ("" + myData.get(Photos.TAG_IMAGE_THUMB_NAME)).replace(" ", "%20");
        System.out.println(uri);
        bimage =  getBitmapFromURL(uri);
        image.setImageBitmap(bimage);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return row;
}
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Please give me some solution for it.

Comment: _What is the problem behind it?_: What problems are you facing? Does it crash? If yes, post the logcat. Any warnings? Post the logcat. If none of these, explain what happens. _in Android 2.2 Images are load but not in Android 4.0 ICS_ is hardly a description.

Comment: it doesn't crash but, in Android 2.2 it shows images that I want, but in Android 4.0, it shows nothing, and there is no error occure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't perform network operations in UI thread starting from Android 3.x. In the LogCat you should see error NetworkOnMainThreadException.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

In your case it is getBitmapFromURL method, which is called from getView. You should use AsyncTask or some Thread

Comment: i am not getting any error, but it display nothing on Android 4.0 else it works in Android 2.2.

Comment: i don't know why you don't see error in Logcat but you can't perform network operations in UI thread on Android ICS

Comment: you are catching exception that is why app is not crashed, but you should see error message in the log

Comment: because on Android 2.2 network operations are allowed in UI thread

Comment: Sorry, i will not do that. Use the same approach as you use in your AsyncData class. Call getBitmapFromURL method in the doInBackground method. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html